Why is my string considered an Invalid Argument in Python?
I am brand new to Python.
I have this as the beginnings of my code which is to read and parse a google doc:
from pathlib import Path

def retrieve_parse_and_print_doc(docURL):
    path = Path(docURL)
    contents = path.read_text()
    lines = contents.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

retrieve_parse_and_print_doc('https://docs.google.com/document/...[elided]/pub')

...but it gives me "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"; I'm running it in VSCode in Windows.
UPDATE
Based on an answer by Jayson Reis here, I changed the code to this:
import requests

def retrieve_parse_and_print_doc(docURL):
    response = requests.get(docURL)
    assert response.status_code == 200, 'Wrong status code'
    lines = response.content.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

retrieve_parse_and_print_doc('https://docs.google.com/document/... [elided]/pub')

...and it sort of works; at least, it returns me a bunch of the page source, as you can see below, but what I want is the values in the table on the page, which seem to be totally obscured amidst all that "gobbledygook" as seen in this image:

How can I parse out the data contained in the table's cells?

Because its got two incompatible types of quotation mark, as per the syntax highlighting

Actually, that happened inadvertently after tying single quotes and then double quotes, and getting that same err. I changed it back to single quotes (both!) and still get the same error.

Path type is supposed to represent the path of a file on the file system. An internet http URL is not a valid path the filesystem. See pathlib tag description: "This module offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems. "

You’ll probably have better luck using the Docs APIs to access the document; here's the documentation for Google docs’ Python client: https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/docs_v1.documents.html#get

pathlib.Path helps you work with files and directories in Python. URLs and directory paths have different structures and rules, so their string causes error.
And about the 'update', the ideal is that you look for an API, this will significantly simplify the work of having to treat this raw data.
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest
